# Laravel unit tests not running on windows

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, eloquent

I was trying to do unit testing with laravel framework.

I followed all the steps described in laravel documentation but it doesn't work when I do "phpunit" command.

Tried the same command on a linux machine, it ran perfectly....

```
Desktop\space-bubble\phpunit.xml


Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.00Mb
```

No tests executed!

Comment: Provide complete error details.

Answer (score 1):

Use the phpunit provided in the project's vendor folder.

Using an unix shell

```sh
~/Desktop/space-bubble
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Using windows cmd

```sh
C:\Users\[your-username]> cd Desktop\space-bubble

C:\Users\[your-username]\Desktop\space-bubble> vendor\bin\phpunit
```